# Spark sql Query to pandas issue

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

So I am running some scripts in an Azure Databricks notebook.
I am querying a table for some data using pySpark.

```
query = """secret sql query""".format(ids)

try:
  DF_sql = spark.sql(query)
```

The query does not prompt any errors but then I try to convert it to a pandas dataframe

```
DF_pd = DF_sql.toPandas()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
 UserWarning: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true, but has reached the error below and can not continue. Note that 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.fallback.enabled' does not have an effect on failures in the middle of computation.
```

The dataframe DF_sql might be empty, would that cause this error? If so how do you handle that gracefully.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is due to empty dataframe, I think you can check if the dataframe is empty and then convert to Pandas Dataframe.

if len(df.head(1)) != 0 :
DF_pd = DF_sql.toPandas()